# A readonly textbox should be cleared on checkbox checked

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Not Required" readonly=readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox"  onclick="CheckCheckboxes1(this)"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Not Required" readonly/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox"  onclick="CheckCheckboxes1(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Not Required" readonly/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox"  onclick="CheckCheckboxes1(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="textbox" value="Not Required" readonly/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox"  onclick="myFunction(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I want to clear textbox when we corresponding checkboc is checked. Here is my Java script,

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function CheckCheckboxes1(chk){

    if(chk.checked == true)
    {
        var txt = document.getElementById('TextBox1');
        txt.value = "";
        txt.disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        var txt = document.getElementById('TextBox1');
        txt.value = "Enter Username";
        txt.disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>
```

Any idea?

Comment: It would be lot more simple if you do with jQuery

Comment: where is Textbox with id 'TextBox1'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the corresponding textbox, you can't get it by ID. Instead you should get the inputs parent table row and then find the input from there, so that it is relative to the checkbox.

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NyXu3/)**

```
function CheckCheckboxes1(chk){
    var txt = chk.parentNode.parentNode.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];

    if(chk.checked == true)
    {
        txt.value = "";
        txt.readOnly = false;
    }
    else
    {
        txt.value = "Enter Username";
        txt.readOnly = true;
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Use `txt.readOnly` not `txt.disabled` because disabled is something different.
- Use the checkbox `onchange` event not `onclick`.

Answer (score 1):

As @Adil said it is easier if you use jQuery. You can give your textbox an id and your checkbox a cutstom attribute e.g.:

```
<td>
 <input type="text" id="txt_1" class="textbox" value="Not Required" readonly=readonly />
</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" specId="1"  onclick="CheckCheckboxes1(this)"/>
        </td>

function CheckCheckboxes1(chk){
      var specId = $(chk).attr("specId");
      var txt = $("#txt_"+specId);

        if(chk.checked == true)
        {                
            $(txt).val("");
            $(txt).attr("disabled","disabled");
        }
        else
        {               
            $(txt).val("Enter Username");
            $(txt).removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Hi in order to disable and enable you need to assign the id's to both checkbox and textboxs. please look at the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

function CheckCheckboxes1(chk){

    if(chk.checked == true)
    {
        var txt = document.getElementById('TextBox'+chk.id);
        txt.value = "";
        txt.disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        var txt = document.getElementById('TextBox'+chk.id);
        txt.value = "Enter Username";
        txt.disabled = true;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id= "TextBox1" class="textbox" value="Not Required" readonly=readonly />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="1" onclick="CheckCheckboxes1(this)"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id= "TextBox2" class="textbox" value="Not Required" readonly/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="2" onclick="CheckCheckboxes1(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>`enter code here`
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id= "TextBox3" class="textbox" value="Not Required" readonly/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="3"  onclick="CheckCheckboxes1(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Value1</td>
        <td>Value2</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id= "TextBox4" class="textbox" value="Not Required" readonly/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" id="4" onclick="myFunction(this)" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>



</body>
</html>
```